# gotemplate not rendering data

Tags: go, templates, webserver, go-templates

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    layout := "static/layout.html"
    tmplFiles := []string{layout, tmpl}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", data)
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmplFiles...)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout.html", data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/directors", directorsHandler)

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    fmt.Println("Server listening on port 8080...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

directors.html
{{ define "content" }}
    Directors ----
    <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {{ range .Directors }}
        hi
        <li>
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{ .Name }}</p>
            <p><strong>Date of Birth:</strong> {{ .DateOfBirth }}</p>
            <p><strong>Nationality:</strong> {{ .Nationality }}</p>
        </li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
{{ end }}

func directorsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := struct {
        Title     string
        Directors []struct {
            Name        string
            DateOfBirth string
            Nationality string
        }
    }{
        Title: "Director List",
        Directors: []struct {
            Name        string
            DateOfBirth string
            Nationality string
        }{
            {
                Name:        "Christopher Nolan",
                DateOfBirth: "July 30, 1970",
                Nationality: "British",
            },
            {
                Name:        "Quentin Tarantino",
                DateOfBirth: "March 27, 1963",
                Nationality: "American",
            },
            // Add more directors as needed
        },
    }
    renderTemplate(w, "static/directors.html", data)
}
```

don't know why .Title is not being rendered.
i have the suspicion that its because the interface but didn't find anything about it.
i am using anonymous struct to send different data to different pages.
I tried to send information to directors.html template content but it wont render.
more details:
the data is being send to data interface{} .

Answer (score 1):

Problem found when sending data to a page with layout you need to write {{template "content" .}} instead of {{ template "content" }}.
needed to add a dot.